# extra line when numbering aligned equations

Tags: equations

When using `align` with a label the equation number appears on a new line when the equation is too long to fit the number. However, when numbering the last of several lines and some of the lines are long, the number takes up a new line even where there is plenty of room on the last line, which is the only one being numbered. Is there a way to force the number not to appear on a new line?

Reasonably minimal example which shows the problem:

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{article}      
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

short equations - no new line

\begin{align} \label{upre1}
&************************ \cr
& ************************
\end{align}

Top equation long - get extra line even though number would fit on bottom line

\begin{align} \label{upre}
&*********************************************** \cr
& ************************
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: could you possibly add a fully compilable MWE?

Comment: `\cr`? Would you try with ``\\`` for ending lines in `align`? Anyhow, I might guess what `\tens` and `\ev` mean, but `\newprime` and `\extd` baffle me. Please, make a full compilable example.

Comment: using \\ gives all lines a number (would make things worse in this case). using \cr only numbers the last line. I have tried to give a working example now.

Comment: @EdwinBeggs Are you aware of `split`?

Comment: no, i have not used split

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what makes you thing that `\cr` is for avoiding to number a line. Use `\nonumber \\` instead

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{article}      
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

Short equations --- no new line
\begin{align} \label{upre1}
&************************ \nonumber \\
& ************************
\end{align}

Top equation long --- get extra line even though number would fit on bottom line
\begin{align}
&******************************************** \nonumber \\
& ************************ \label{upre}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Note that the `\label` should go in the numbered line.

[image]

Comment: could you also tell what is the purpose for `\cr` and where to (correctly) use it?

Comment: @Raaja `\cr` is a primitive and nobody is supposed to use it in the body of a document.